# Automatically add Scenario name to filename of screenshot in Selenium using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm using Selenium, writing in Ruby.  I've configured my env.rb file to save a screenshot of any failed tests that I run.  The problem is it's hard to determine the scenario/step that failed as the filename is generic.  I've managed to time stamp the filename using this:

```
After do |scenario|
    if scenario.failed?
       screenshot_file = "screenshot - #{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')}.png"
       page.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)
     end
end
```

Is there a way in which I can get this filename to also pull the name of the scenario that failed so that it could be "scenario# date time.png"? I've seen a few examples online, none of which work.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `scenario.name`

Comment: I did, but i wasn't sure where to put that.  Would it be #{scenario.name}#{time etc}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
screenshot_file = "screenshot-#{scenario.name}-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')}.png"
...
```

Comment: I tried that, the screenshot fails to save.  I'm wondering whether it's how i've named my scenario... "Scenario: US1244-1.1 Confirm that the View all fleet records form contais a section to allow user to Filter results by Registration number and Vehicle make"  Maybe it doesn't like that

Comment: it could be the file length issue. Use a short scenario name and check if it works.

Comment: That was exactly it.  Your help is much appreciated